# SQL Error 1064 when trying to import dump in node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, phpmyadmin, sequelize.js

I'm trying to programatically import the dump of a MySQL database into a fresh instance using node.js / Sequelize. I exported the old database via phpMyAdmin and saved it into a text file.

Then I am doing the following:

```
fs.readFile('./sql/dump.sql', 'utf-8', function(err, data){
    sequelize.query(data).success(function(data){
        done.resolve(data);
    }).fail(function(err){
        done.reject(err);
    });
});
```

in my import script. This fails with:

```
[Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
 that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
'CREATE DATABASE `db456668865` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_c
i' at line 13]
  code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0
```

This is strange as I never touched the SQL data and would expect phpMyAdmin to generate valid SQL (also I cannot see any syntax error in the part that is mentioned). Even stranger is the fact that when I try to import the SQL dump via the phpMyAdmin interface of the database I am trying to import things into it is also working perfectly. What is it that is keeping me from doing this programatically?

**EDIT**:
I initialize the `sequelize` like this:

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize(dbConfig.db, dbConfig.user, dbConfig.pass, {
    host : dbConfig.host
    , port : dbConfig.port
});
```

I can use the instance perfectly fine for any other operations.

Comment: Show us how you construct the sequelizer

Comment: @MattEsch added that to the question.

Comment: I think it's probably either a quote problem or it's a problem with having multiple statements in your query

Comment: I'm pretty sure @MattEsch is right: you can't have multiple statements in your query. The [`node-mysql`](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#connection-options) driver has an option to allow multiple statements per query, but I don't think Sequelize has.

Comment: Following up on @robertklep's comment - I'm pretty sure multi statements are the culprit here. Have a look at https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-doc/blob/master/views/documentation/sections/usage/options.md for how to pass options to the underlying library

Comment: @JanAagaardMeier perfect, that was just the missing piece I was looking for. Works just like it should now when passing the correct option. Would you mind adding your comment as an answer?